# How can I use stripe.js with jQuery.payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

jQuery.payment expects expiration to be in a single value, but stripe expects separate values for month and year. how do the two libraries work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stripe.card.createToken` can accept the card data in the object in addition to accepting a raw HTMLForm.

If using a single expiry field you can get the value from the form and then split it into a month and year yourself to use in Stripe.js' exp_month and exp_year.

Comment: I ended up just splitting them in javascript.

Comment: Oh, also it seems that if you call `$yourInput.payment('cardExpiryVal')` jQuery.payment will return an object containing month and year keys.